# converting the dataset tables to WCF data member class type

Tags: c#, wcf

I am retrieving relational dataset( 2 tables) from DB.

I have a DataContract defined like below :

```
public class DetailData
{
    [DataMember]
    public Customer_Detail Detail;
    [DataMember]
    public Relationship_Detail Relationship_Detail;
}
[DataContract(Name = "Detail")]
public class Customer_Detail
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string NAME { get; set; }
}
[DataContract(Name = "Relationship Detail")]
public class Relationship_Detail
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string STATUS { get; set; }
 }
```

Now In My data access layer I need to assign the dataset table1 value to  "Customer_Detail" and the second table value to "Relationship_Detail".

How can I achieve this?

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? nHibernate?  If not you could just use _AutoMapper_

Comment: loop over `dataSet.Tables[0].Rows` and assign to relevant POCO may be.

Comment: I tried to loop through to ass. But it says can not convert the datatable to the specified object(my data member class name)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this -

```
obj.Prop1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(a => new Test{ Name = a.Field<int>("Name"), Age = a.Field<string>("Age") }).ToList();

obj.Prop2 = ds.Tables[1].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(a => new Test2{ Name2 = a.Field<int>("Name"), Age2 = a.Field<string>("Age") }).ToList();
```